Adjusting vertical spacing between title number and title in scrreprt
I am using LuaLaTeX to compile my document.
After encountering a formatting issue with my table of contents (see here), I switched to KOMA-Script document class scrreprt.
I have successfully adapted my titles formatting with KOMA-Script standards. However, I am unsure how to adjust the vertical spacing between the title numbering and the title itself.
Specifically, I would like a consistent 12pt vertical space between the numbering ("Première partie," "Chapitre 1") and the title itself ("Titre de la partie 1," "Titre du chapitre 1") for both /part and /chapter titles.
The part titles appear on dedicated pages, but they should have the same style and spacing as chapter titles. In my example, the difference is very minimal, but it does exist.
Please find below the MWE:
% --- main.tex ---
\documentclass[12pt,sfdefaults=false,chapterprefix,numbers=noenddot,twoside]{scrreprt}

% --- Packages ---
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% --- Fonts ---
\setmainfont[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Numbers=Lining,
    UprightFont={AGaramondPro-Regular.otf},    
    BoldFont={AGaramondPro-Bold.otf},
    ItalicFont={AGaramondPro-Italic.otf},
    BoldItalicFont={AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.otf},
    SemiBold={AGaramondPro-SemiBold.otf},
    SemiBoldItalic={AGaramondPro-SemiBoldItalic.otf}
]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
% Police semibold
\newfontface\semiboldfont[Contextuals={WordInitial,WordFinal}]{AGaramondPro-SemiBold.otf}

% --- Titles Style ---
% Part Title Style
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\strut\fontsize{18pt}{22pt}\normalfont}\setkomafont{part}{\strut\fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=36pt]{part}
\renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\raggedsection}

% Chapter Titles Style
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\strut\fontsize{18pt}{22pt}\normalfont Chapitre~\thechapter}\setkomafont{chapter}{\strut\fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=36pt]{chapter}

% Section Titles Style
\setkomafont{section}{\strut\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=24pt, afterskip=12pt]{section}

\begin{document}
\part{Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}

EDIT: Replacing parskip by parskip=half somehow solved the following issue!
Another issue concerns the differences in spacing between chapter titles and the text that follows. These differences seem to be caused by the presence or absence of descending letters.
For example, the spacing between "Titre du chapitre 1" and following text is not the same as between "Conclusion" and following text. The difference is barely noticeable, but it is there.
I had used the command \vphantom{gjpqybdhlt} in each chapter title to avoid these spacing inconsistencies. This worked, but I was told it's not the most optimal solution. However, I haven’t found any better alternatives
I suspect this problem may be related to the font I am using (Adobe Garamond Pro). When I revert the font configuration to default font, vertical spacing discrepancies seems to be resolved. Do you have any idea where this problem might come from and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Best,
Sam

Welcome to TeX.SX! I can't reproduce your second issue if I comment the \setmainfont and \newfontface commands (I haven't the font on my system).

By the way you should replace the parskip package by the parskip=half option of scrreprt.

Thank you, replacing parskip by parskip=half somehow solved the second issue! I'll update my post accordingly.

Can you show an example using a free font? I do not own Adobe Garamond Pro. So I cannot test anything. But note, the space between the number prefix line and the text line of headings with style part and chapter can be modified using innerskip (see Table 20.3 and 20.4 in the KOMA-Script documentation). BTW: \strut is not a font command, but a command with output and therefore should not be used in the argument of \setkomafont.

Additionally, because of using the default vertical adjustment (see the difference of \flushbottom and \raggedbottom) but lengths without glue, I'd expect underfull/overfull \vbox or badbox warnings, e.g., for pages with chapter headings.

KOMA-Script's definition of heading styles part (used by \part) and chapter (used by \chapter) are somehow different and therefore the space between the prefix line and the text line of a heading seems to be somehow different, depending on using class option parskip.
Additionally you've added several \strut commands, where they are not allowed and not recommended. Something like the following should IMHO work also if you change the font. But if you change the font sizes or baselineskip you may need to adapt the innerskip values.
% --- main.tex ---
\documentclass[12pt,sfdefaults=false,chapterprefix,numbers=noenddot,twoside,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

% --- Packages ---
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% --- Fonts ---
%\setmainfont[
%    Ligatures=TeX,
%    Numbers=Lining,
%    UprightFont={AGaramondPro-Regular.otf},    
%    BoldFont={AGaramondPro-Bold.otf},
%    ItalicFont={AGaramondPro-Italic.otf},
%    BoldItalicFont={AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.otf},
%    SemiBold={AGaramondPro-SemiBold.otf},
%    SemiBoldItalic={AGaramondPro-SemiBoldItalic.otf}
%]%{Adobe Garamond Pro}
% Police semibold
% \newfontface\semiboldfont[Contextuals={WordInitial,WordFinal}]{AGaramondPro-SemiBold.otf}

% --- Titles Style ---
% Part Title Style
\setkomafont{partprefix}{\fontsize{18pt}{22pt}\normalfont}
\setkomafont{part}{\fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,innerskip=7.5pt,afterskip=36pt]{part}
\renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\raggedsection}

% Chapter Titles Style
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\fontsize{18pt}{22pt}\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=36pt,innerskip=0pt]{chapter}

% Section Titles Style
\setkomafont{section}{\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=24pt, afterskip=12pt]{section}

% Used for debugging
% \usepackage{xcolor}
% \DeclareRobustCommand*{\linemarkbox}{%
%   \makebox[0pt][l]{\color{yellow}\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}}
% }

% \AddToHook{cmd/FB@partname/before}{\hskip-1pt\smash{\rule[\dimeval{-12pt-\dp\strutbox}]{1pt}{12pt}}\linemarkbox}
% \AddToHook{cmd/chapterformat/before}{\hskip-1pt\smash{\rule[\dimeval{-12pt-\dp\strutbox}]{1pt}{12pt}}\linemarkbox}

\begin{document}
\part{%\linemarkbox % used for debugging
  Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{% \linemarkbox % used for debugging
  Titre du chapitre 1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}

Note (once again), that \fontsize{12pt}{12pt} or in general using the same value for the font size and the baselineskip is not a good idea. Because you are using 12pt as class option, I've just removed it. Another suggestion would be to use \normalsize.
Note also, that anyfontsize is not needed when using scalable fonts and therefore makes not sense when using fontspec.

Another suggestion would be to change the style of \part also to chapter, so you can use the same values to get the same formatting:
% --- main.tex ---
\documentclass[12pt,sfdefaults=false,chapterprefix,numbers=noenddot,twoside,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

% --- Packages ---
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% --- Fonts ---
%\setmainfont[
%    Ligatures=TeX,
%    Numbers=Lining,
%    UprightFont={AGaramondPro-Regular.otf},    
%    BoldFont={AGaramondPro-Bold.otf},
%    ItalicFont={AGaramondPro-Italic.otf},
%    BoldItalicFont={AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.otf},
%    SemiBold={AGaramondPro-SemiBold.otf},
%    SemiBoldItalic={AGaramondPro-SemiBoldItalic.otf}
%]%{Adobe Garamond Pro}
% Police semibold
% \newfontface\semiboldfont[Contextuals={WordInitial,WordFinal}]{AGaramondPro-SemiBold.otf}

% --- Titles Style ---
% Part Title Style
\setkomafont{partprefix}{\fontsize{18pt}{22pt}\normalfont}
\setkomafont{part}{\fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter,beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=36pt,innerskip=0pt]{part}

% Chapter Titles Style
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\fontsize{18pt}{22pt}\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=36pt,innerskip=0pt]{chapter}

% Section Titles Style
\setkomafont{section}{\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=24pt, afterskip=12pt]{section}

% Used for debugging
% \usepackage{xcolor}
% \DeclareRobustCommand*{\linemarkbox}{%
%   \makebox[0pt][l]{\color{yellow}\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}}
% }

% \AddToHook{cmd/FB@partname/before}{\hskip-1pt\smash{\rule[\dimeval{-12pt-\dp\strutbox}]{1pt}{12pt}}\linemarkbox}
% \AddToHook{cmd/chapterformat/before}{\hskip-1pt\smash{\rule[\dimeval{-12pt-\dp\strutbox}]{1pt}{12pt}}\linemarkbox}

\begin{document}
\part{%\linemarkbox % used for debugging
  Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{% \linemarkbox % used for debugging
  Titre du chapitre 1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}


However, using style chapter also means other changes, e.g., \part is not automatically a (double) page on its own (but if \part{…} is always followed by \chapter{…} this is not really important).

Thank you for your help and patience. This solution works! I also removed \strut and adjusted all baselineskip values to 20% of the current font size.

@slalomeuse If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider upvoting (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Sure, did it! By the way, do you know if there is a way to do the same with \title? I've experienced similar issues with vertical spacing between title and top margin which appear to be slightly different than between part or chapter and top margin even though I've put a \vspace*{0pt} before it. The idea is to get my title + subtitle the same style, spacing and position as parts or chapters. (Title with same style as \part or \chapter and subtitle the same style as \partprefix or \chapterprefix). No problem with fonts style, but mostly with position and spacing

@slalomeuse \title is a completely other concept. It just sets a variable, that is printed by \maketitle. And \maketitle produces not only a heading, but a complete title page with author, date etc. It can even produce several pages. If you want a title, that is only a heading, just use \part*{Title}. If you want a more configurable title either use a package like uni-titlepage or the titlepage environment or another free formatted title. But this would be a completely other question.
